# xlsxwriter conditional format on forumla cell requires a manual recalculate when the sheet is opened

Tags: python, pandas, excel

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20.5, 30, 40, 50.7, 62, 70]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})

for i in range(2, len(df)+2):
    worksheet.write_formula("C"+str(i), "=SUM(B{}:B6)".format(i))
    #print(i)
#worksheet.conditional_format('C2:C8', {'type': '3_color_scale', 'min_color':'#63BE7B', 'mid_color':'#FCFCFF','max_color':'#F8696B'})
worksheet.conditional_format('C2:C8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

When I open the resulting spreadsheet, column C doesn't display the conditional formatting correctly.

[image]

However, after manually hitting F9 to recalculate the sheet it looks fine.

I understand that xlswriter doesn't evaluate formulas and that they are evaluated by excel when the sheet is opened. Is there a way to get excel to apply the conditional formatting when the sheet is opened too, instead of manually triggering a recalculate?

Comment: Seems impossible unless you fill in the computed numbers yourself - plz see the [Formula Results](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-results) section of the official XLSX documentation: "XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the result of a formula and instead stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened.... If required, it is also possible to specify the calculated result of he formula using the optional value parameter for write_formula():.."